# Best way to find Users with certain associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Lets say I have a `User` model and each user has an association called `user_logins` which is created every time they login, storing information about their login.

What I need to do is find all users that have 5 user_login records, where the fifth record was created today.

Something like this:

```
users = User.all.where(user_logins_count == 5, user_login.last.created_at == today)
```

`user_logins_count` is a counter cache I have set up.

Of course that code is brutal, but hopefully it'll elaborate on what I'm trying to achieve.

PG ERROR

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "last
"
LINE 1: ...n_logins_count" = 5 GROUP BY humans.id HAVING MAX(human_logi...
                                                             ^
```

New code:

```
humans = user.humans.joins(:human_logins).where(human_logins_count: 5)
        .group('humans.id')
        .having('MAX(human_logins.created_at) >= ?', Date.today)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define this as a scope inside the `User` class:

```
class User
  scope :logged_in_a_lot_today, -> do
    joins(:user_logins).where(user_logins_count: 5)
      .group('users.id')
      .having('MAX(user_logins.created_at) >= ?', Date.today)
  end
end
```

Now you can simply get these users with:

```
User.logged_in_a_lot_today
```

Since it's defined as a scope, you can also add more conditions if you'd like to:

```
User.logged_in_a_lot_today.where(name: 'John Doe')
```

Note that it would probably be a good idea to set up a partial index (if your database supports it) on users who have a `user_logins_count` of 5.

Comment: Thanks fivedigit, will the joins and group work in postgres? as I know it can be somewhat sketchy with them calls

Comment: I've actually tested this in postgres, so it should work like a charm! ;)

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if it works, otherwise I can change the answer :)

Comment: It seems you're doing a little different kind of query there. Make sure you're doing a join with the humans table.

Comment: Think I sorted that, it seems to be returning the user found 5 times though, which is weird.

Comment: In my example that doesn't happen because I group on user ID. Try appending `uniq` to the relation to only select distinct rows.

Comment: By the way, if my answer fixed your original question, please accept it as an answer.

Comment: I'll add my code to the main thread, can you please show how I would use uniq? Haven't had to use it before.

Comment: It would be better to ask a new question and refer to this one, as it's a different problem.

Comment: You may want to consider `Time.current` or `Time.zone.now` instead of `Date.today` to ensure you don't get strange behaviors because of time zone differences. See: http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2014/10/22/use-time-zone-now-instead-of-time-now/

Comment: Ok will do, one more question regarding this solution. When calling .count on the outcome I get {8=>5} where 8 is the user id and 5 is the count or id of the user_logins. I was expecting count to return 1, any idea why its acting this way?